# Find an array in a string

Tags: c#, selenium, web, webdriver

I am working with the Selenium API in C#.
I try to read a script and get the needed values from that.

```
string attackable_villages = web.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content_value']/script[1]")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
richTextBox1.Text = attackable_villages;
```

The result I get:

```
result.scrollBound = {
    x_min: 0,
    x_max: 999,
    y_min: 0,
    y_max: 999
};

result.tileSize = [53, 38];

result.screenKey = 'bf14559d';
result.topoKey = 4133874391;
```

and many more..

But there is this:

```
result.thisiswhatiwant= [1value1, 1value2, 1value3, 1value4..], [2value1, 2value2, 2value3, ...], [...]
```

How can I just get that array without the rest and split all elements after `"],"`

I hope you can help me!

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Split the script in its individual statements
var splitArray = script.Split(';');
// Get the statement you're interested in
var line = splitArray.Where(x => x.Contains("result.thisiswhatiwant")).First();         
// Remove all characters except numbers and commas, then split by comma       
var values = Regex.Replace(line, "[^0-9,]", string.Empty).Split(',');
```

Testing with this input:

```
 string script = "test; result.thisiswhatiwant=[1,2,3]; three;";
```

gives me an array of length 3 (with values 1/2/3 respectively).
You can also use `Single(...)` instead of `Where(...).First()` if the statement occurs only once.

Comment: and I can use the split method again in my "line" to split the categories with like `.Split(']')` ?

Comment: Yes, try to experiment with the possibilities, you should get there. You can always use a Regex.Match if you need more flexibility.